# Left child, right sibling binary tree with strings

Tags: c++, string, printing, binary-tree, destructor

I am writing a program to create a tree-based data structure for storing a collection of strings, arbitrarily called "Pxtree". The program is a modification of the **left child right sibling** binary tree problem, involving **dynamic memory** and **pointers**, without the use of a node structure/class.

The data structure takes the form of a tree. Each node in the tree is associated with a single character (and an integer representing the counts, to be explained later). Each node can also have any number of children. The children of a node are kept in an order based on when they are inserted/removed (so not necessarily in alphabetical order).

Characters are stored in the nodes in such a way that the strings can be traced by following a path that starts from the root and choosing one of the children at each node. The characters at each node are concatenated to give the string. An alternative way of looking at this is that each string is represented by a path of individual letters, but strings that share some beginning letters (or prefixes) have those parts of their paths merged. As a result, no two children of a node should contain the same character.

The root node of the tree contains a special character '\0' that is not part of any string.

The printed tree should take the form like this:

```
h 0
  e 0
    l 0
      l 0
        o 1
      p 1
```

Where the inputted strings in this example are "hello" and "help".

The integer next to each character displays whether it is the end of the string or not. If the integer is 1, then the character is the end of the string. If it is greater than 1, this indicates that the same string is present multiple times in the tree.

I have written multiple functions within the program already: a default constructor, a copy constructor/copy assignment, the integer count, and the add and remove functions to allow the input and removal of a string. *Note: removing the string does not entirely remove the string but sets its final character's integer count to 0.*

Here is my code so far:

Pxtree.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Pxtree.h"
using namespace std;

Pxtree::Pxtree() { // default constructor
        c_ = '\0';
        count_ = 0;

        leftmostChild_ = nullptr;
        nextSibling_ = nullptr;
}

Pxtree::~Pxtree() { // destructor

Pxtree::Pxtree(const Pxtree& other) { // copy constructor
        leftmostChild_ = other.leftmostChild_;
        nextSibling_ = other.nextSibling_;

        c_ = other.c_;
        count_ = other.count_;
}

Pxtree& Pxtree::operator=(const Pxtree& other) { // copy assignment
        if (&other != this) {
                c_ = other.c_;

                if (other.nextSibling_ == nullptr) nextSibling_ = nullptr;
                else nextSibling_ = new Pxtree(*other.nextSibling_);
        }
        return *this;
}

int Pxtree::count(string s) const { // integer count
        if (c_ == '\0') {
                if (leftmostChild_ == nullptr) return 0;
                else return leftmostChild_->count(s);
        }
        else if (c_ == s[0]) {
                if (s.length() == 1) return count_;
                else if (leftmostChild_ == nullptr) return 0;
                else return leftmostChild_->count(s.erase(0,1));
        }
        else {
                if (nextSibling_ == nullptr) return 0;
                else return nextSibling_->count(s);
        }
}

void Pxtree::add(string s) { // add string function
        Pxtree *p = this;

        for (char c : s) {
                if (p->leftmostChild_ != nullptr) {
                        if (p->leftmostChild_->c_ == c) p = p->leftmostChild_;
                        else if (p->nextSibling_ != nullptr) {
                                while (p->nextSibling_ != nullptr) {
                                        if (p->nextSibling_->c_ == c) {
                                                p = p->nextSibling_;
                                                break;
                                        }
                                        p = p->nextSibling_;
                                }
                                if (p->c_ == c) continue;
                                if (p->nextSibling_ == nullptr) {
                                        printf("Add sibling %c\n", c);

                                        auto *node = new Pxtree();

                                        node->c_ = c;
                                        node->count_ = 0;
                                        node->leftmostChild_ = nullptr;
                                        node->nextSibling_ = nullptr;

                                        p->nextSibling_ = node;
                                }
                        }
                        else {
                                printf("Add sibling %c\n", c);

                                auto *node = new Pxtree();

                                node->c_ = c;
                                node->count_ = 0;
                                node->leftmostChild_ = nullptr;
                                node->nextSibling_ = nullptr;

                                p->nextSibling_ = node;
                                p = node;
                        }
                }
                else {
                        printf("Add child %c\n", c);

                        auto *node = new Pxtree();

                        node->c_ = c;
                        node->count_ = 0;
                        node->leftmostChild_ = nullptr;
                        node->nextSibling_ = nullptr;

                        p->leftmostChild_ = node;
                        p = node;
                }
        }
        p->count_++;
}

void Pxtree::remove(string s) {
        Pxtree *p = this;
        if (s.length() == 0) return;

        for (char c : s) {
                if (p->leftmostChild_ != nullptr) {
                        if (p->leftmostChild_->c_ == c) {
                                p = p->leftmostChild_;
                                printf("%c\n", p->c_);
                                printf("count: %d\n", p->count_);
                        }
                        else if (p->nextSibling_ != nullptr) {
                                while (p->nextSibling_ != nullptr) {
                                        if (p->nextSibling_->c_ == c) {
                                                p = p->nextSibling_;
                                                break;
                                        }
                                        p = p->nextSibling_;
                                }
                                if (p->c_ == 0) {
                                        printf("%c\n", c);
                                        printf("count: %d\n", p->count_);
                                        continue;
                                }
                                if (p->nextSibling_ == nullptr) return;
                                if (p->nextSibling_->c_ == c) {
                                        p = p->nextSibling_;
                                        printf("%c\n", p->c_);
                                        printf("count: %d\n", p->count_);
                                }
                        }
                        else return;
                }
        }
        p->count_--;
        printf("final count: %d\n", p->count_);
}

string Pxtree::print() const {
}

string Pxtree::autoComplete(string s) const {
}

void Pxtree::compact() {
}
```

Pxtree.h:

```
#ifndef PXTREE_H_
#define PXTREE_H_

#include <string>
using std::string;

class Pxtree {
public:
        Pxtree();
        ~Pxtree();
        Pxtree(const Pxtree& other);
        Pxtree& operator=(const Pxtree& other);
        int count(string s) const;
        void add(string s);
        void remove(string s);
        string print() const;
        string autoComplete(string s) const;
        void compact();

private:
        char c_;
        int count_;
        Pxtree* leftmostChild_;
        Pxtree* nextSibling_;
};

#endif
```

I am struggling to write code for the **destructor** (~Pxtree()) and the **print function** (string print() const); I'm not really sure where to start.

Comment: Here's a simple way to figure out "where to start", and it never fails to work. Just take out a blank sheet of paper. Write down using short, simple sentences in plain English, a step-by-step process of your destructor code. When done, [call your rubber duck for an appointment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). We don't write code for other people, on Stackoverflow. We always refer such questions to your rubber duck. After your rubber duck approves your proposed plan of action, simply take what you've written down and translate it directly into C++. Mission accomplished!

Comment: I assume this is an assignment?  The right way to do this is a trie.  You get very quick lookip and (practically) less memory overhead, especially if you permit strings in the node (for when there is only one child).  This method looks over complex and error prone.  If you do use this method, be sane and use unique ptr, or more sane and have a vector of children.